# How to find the source of a message, output by Qt?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

When running my qt application, that is updated from qt 5.9 to qt 5.15, I get the following application output:

```
Using QByteRef with an index pointing outside the valid range of a QByteArray
```

The application is quite big and has plenty qbytearrays and qbyterefs.  The project is a few thousand files big so I do not want to search for it manually.  Is there an easy way to find the location of the application output. e.g. show the line/file that generates the output.
The line is generated by qt and not a custom qdebug or anything.

Comment: You could try installing your own [message handler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler) and setting a breakpoint in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you to check *Stop when qWarning() is called* under the *Debugger* section of the Qt Creator's *Options*:

[image]

By default, this option is off, as shown in the screenshot.